# Recursive Determinant only works for 2x2 and 3x3, nothing larger (C++)

Tags: c++, recursion, matrix

I wrote a `C++` program to find the `determinant` of any `NxN matrix`. It works for a `2x2` and `3x3`, but returns arbitrary and incorrect values for any `4x4` or larger matrix. I can post snippets of my code as needed. I feel that this is a common issue when writing recursive methods to calculate a determinant of a square matrix. If anyone has had a similar experience and can offer me any tips, they would be much appreciated!

Comment: Look into [LU decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition).

Comment: Please post [mcve]

Comment: Formatted question description.

Comment: `I can post snippets of my code as needed` - then post it. `I feel that this is a common issue` - no, not really.